# Your ideas on my though "delete or move all of the posts in a specific category when 3 days are passed"

Tags: posts, database

I need to clean up my database and I think that a way to do and keep it that way is by deleting all posts that have 3 days of life. One good thing is that those posts I want to delete are in a specific category.

So, how can I clean up my database correctly by deleting or moving thoem and also their posts_meta or terms or anything ? I want to just have/show the posts that are 3 days or earlier.

Comment: what would you do about the returning 404 errors for when these pages are indexed, if your deleting posts after 3 days it sounds like you have a content rich site and with continually added content i would dare say these 3 day old pages would be getting indexed pretty quickly..

Comment: You mean indexed from google? Basically I use my page as a "share your post" with their permalink and stuf through tdo mini forms.

Comment: Rather than deleting the actual content, have you thought about altering your theme so it only shows the content from the last 3 days?

Comment: Well yes, but will this speed up my system? I have 70.000 posts, I think that even a single query lasts longer.

Comment: You have to send a 410 status header or your page trust will fall like a stone. It is easier just to close the site.

Comment: @ toscho thats what i was thinking too, maybe a good idea to code up a little function to drop in a meta tag "expires" to let the search engine bots (Google in this case as i think its the only one that recognises meta tag expires), whatever the op chooses it needs carefull planning and fore-thought to keep credability with search engines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a quick plugin i cooked for you :)

```
 <?php
/*
Plugin Name: Post Auto Removal
Plugin URI: http://en.bainternet.info
Description: Post Auto Removal lets you schedule when the post / page / custom type will be deleted automatically.
Version: 0.1
Author: bainternet
Author URI: http://en.bainternet.info
*/


/* hook meta box */
add_action("admin_init", "admin_init");

/* hook meta box function */
function admin_init(){
    add_meta_box("Post Auto Removal", "Post Auto Removal", "Post_Auto_Removal_options", "post", "normal", "high");
    add_meta_box("Post Auto Removal", "Post Auto Removal", "Post_Auto_Removal_options", "page", "normal", "high");
}

/* display meta box */
function Post_Auto_Removal_options() {
    global $post;
    $custom['active_removal'] = get_post_meta($post->ID,'active_removal',true);
    $custom['Remove_after'] = get_post_meta($post->ID,'Remove_after',true);
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="wp_meta_box_nonce" value="'. wp_create_nonce('Auto_Removal'). '" />';
?>
    <table border=0>
      <tr>
        <th style="width:20%"><label for="active_removal">Activate auto removal:</label></th>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="active_removal" id="active_removal" value="yes" <?php echo $custom['active_removal'] ? 'checked' : ''; ?>/><br/>
        when check post will be deleted in the given time.
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th style="width:20%"><label for="Remove_after">Delete post after:</label></th>
        <td><input type="text" name="Remove_after" id="Remove_after" value="<?php echo $custom['Remove_after'] ? $custom['Remove_after'] : ''; ?>"/><br/>
        Enter time in Seconds Ex: 1 Hour = 3600 Seconds , 1 Day = 86400 Seconds.
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php  
    $next = wp_get_schedule( 'Clean_my_posts', array($post_id));
    print_r($next);
    if ($next){ ?>
    <tr>
    <th>next schedule is set to : <?php echo $next; ?></th>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>

    </table>
<?php }

/* save meta box hook*/
add_action('save_post', 'save_Post_Auto_Removal_options');

/* save meta box function*/
function save_Post_Auto_Removal_options($post_id) {
    if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['wp_meta_box_nonce'], "Auto_Removal")) {
        return $post_id;
    }
    // check autosave
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
        return $post_id;
    }
    If (isset($_POST['Remove_after']) && isset($_POST['active_removal'])){
        //cerate scheduled event
        $time = time() + $_POST['Remove_after'];
        wp_schedule_single_event($time, 'Clean_my_posts',array($post_id));
        //save meta data
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'Remove_after', $_POST['Remove_after']);
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'active_removal', $_POST['active_removal']);

    }    
}


 /* hook removal event function */
  add_action('Clean_my_posts','auto_remove_post',1,1);

// the function that deletes a post everything that is tied to it, This includes comments, post meta fields, and terms associated with the post.
function auto_remove_post($post_id) {
    $delete = get_post_meta($post_id, 'active_removal', true);
    if ($delete){
        wp_delete_post( $post_id, true ); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this. So what it does, it auto deletes expired posts (3 days) and anything related to it right?
How can I delete or transfer in another database all the posts on a specific category and anything related to it?

Comment: Bainternet do you accept work as a freelancer? I feel I will need you for some simple scripts quite soon.

Comment: @punkis It adds a new metabox which lets you select if you want the post or the page auto deleted it self after any amount of time you specify. and yes i do accept work as a freelancer.

Comment: Ok then! I will need you in a month for some scripts. How can I contact you ?

Comment: click my image under the answer or anywhere on this site you see my name, from there you can see the link to my site , feel free to do so.